# kohana order group by and count

Tags: orm, count, group-by, kohana

I have orm query like tthis:

```
$userCountries = ORM::factory('User')
                ->select(array(DB::expr('countries.code, COUNT("countries.id") as total')))
                ->join('countries')
                ->on('user.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
                ->group_by('country.name')
                ->order_by('total', 'DESC')
                ->find_all();
```

What i want is country code with total users quantity from country.

I do not know what is wrong here. I spent 3 hours on it with no success.

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: There may be nothing wrong with the query, though you use the ORM library. This means that `$userCountries` is filled with ORM models of type `User`. Try rewriting the query using `DB::select()`, this should only take changing a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT Params is wrong
`->select('countries.code', array(DB::expr('COUNT("countries.id")', 'total')))`

I think the Group by should be 
`->group_by('countries.name') instead of ->group_by('country.name')`

So Your Total Query will look like

```
$userCountries = ORM::factory('User')
            ->select('countries.code', array(DB::expr('COUNT("countries.id")', 'total')))
            ->join('countries')
            ->on('user.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
            ->group_by('countries.name')
            ->order_by('total', 'DESC')
            ->find_all();`
```

Check this out...

Comment: thanks, something is wrong here. I have Undefined offset: 1 - error